# Open source C# compilers in C#?

Tags: c#, open-source, compiler-construction

Are there any open source C# compilers written in C#?

I know of `Blue`, but it was written in 2001 and only supports C# 1:

- [Mike Stall's 'Blue' C# Compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/02/06/368192.aspx)

Ideally, I'm looking for one which supports C# 3.0 - but even 2.0 would be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mono's [C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) is written in C#. If you need to just parse C# source text, you may use NRefactory.

Comment: Good find, I never realised Mono's compiler was written in C# itself.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [mono C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler), which is written in C# itself. You can browse the source [here](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/mcs/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is another one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cscompiler.aspx), but also quite old, from 2002.

Comment: That's not a c# compiler, it uses the framework features to compile the code.

Comment: Well, technically, it is indeed "a C# compiler written in C#". The question does not specifically ask for a compiler written from scratch.